# Create a virtual COM port for Bluetooth in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, bluetooth, serial-port

I have an app. that receives some transmissions from a device via Bluetooth. This app is meant to be hosted on Win. Server 2008 or Win. 7, developed on C#.NET 4.5. The integration is made by using the device SDK, so I just need to know which is the COM port to receive data from. That's not a problem when I create the virtual COM port manually from the Bluetooth settings.

[image: Virtual COM port]
.

This integration should be deployed in lots of devices, and asking users to create a virtual COM port manually is not an option... Is there a way of creating it from .NET code? I would need to create the virtual COM port (listening for Bluetooth transmissions) and know its port name.

EDIT: I'm open to new ways of doing that (C++, power shell scripts, CMD, bat file... always inside Windows technologies

I have tried already some COM integration ([like this one](https://github.com/hjgode/btComPrint/blob/master/btComPrint/BluetoothSerialPort.cs)), but it seems to be limited to .NetCF (I don't have coredll.dll since it is running on Windows Server or Windows 7, among other missing stuff... already tried to 'force' that DLL to load with no luck). Something similar, but working, would be the ideal solution

Answer (score 3):

I found this interesting tidbit that relates to your problem

> On Win32, to create a Bluetooth virtual serial port one can use
>   BluetoothDeviceInfo.SetServiceState, passing in service class
>   SerialPort. Unfortunately the name of the COM port created is not
>   returned — that’s because the native API does not tell! One way to
>   find the name of the port created is to call the
>   System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames method before and after the
>   SetServiceState call and see which name is new.

Source: https://github.com/inthehand/32feet/wiki/Bluetooth-Serial-Ports

In any case... In the registry, All bluetooth devices are listed under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\BTHENUM`.

You can enumerate the entries under that key to locate your device PNP ID.
A key name from my registry, as an example: 
`{00001103-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_VID&0001001d_PID&1200`

The serial port for your device is stored below that, in: 
`.\{unique subkey name}\Device Parameters\SerialPort`

Where {unique subkey name} is an internal MS ID.  It's the only subkey at that level.

One way to get the PnPID is to right-click->Property on the device in Device Manager.  Go to the "Details" tab, then select "Compatible IDs" in the combo box.

Comment: Thanks Michael! It seems we can have it working on that way. I have tried to make it work, but I'm not sure on how to instantiate BluetoothDeviceInfo.
If I'm not wrong: the idea is to pair the BT device before creating the virtual COM port, then obtain its PNP ID and parse it as a BluetoothAddress to instantiate a BluetoothDeviceInfo? May the device be paired after creating the virtual COM port? I'm not an expert in this issue, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: That's the idea.  Your device PnP ID is in the `VID&xxxxxxxd_PID&xxxx` part of the key, and you should use that to recover the port.  the PnP ID may also have a revision attached to it. The serial port  can be recovered this way anytime after the port was created.  The key will be present after the first pairing, even when the device is not connected.

Comment: Hey @MichaëlRoy, thanks once again. Is there a way of creating the virtual COM port **before** pairing the BT device? The issue with this method is, I should have the device paired then I would get its PnP ID. But 'by hand', I can create a virtual COM port without needing a device paired. Do you know if there is a way for doing that from the code? Thanks once again!

Comment: No, you can't.  The device has to be paired.  If the device is made by you, you should have its PnPID.

Comment: Ok, I see. The issue is: this is a 3rd. party device. I can create a virtual COM port (by hand) before pairing it from BT settings. This device has a SDK, and it doesn't transmit data until the VCOM gets created. That's why I'm looking for creating the VCOM before pairing the device, just as I do it by hand.

Comment: after pairing the device with a PC, I don't have anything under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\BTHENUM
I have rebooted, refreshed... still nothing. But the devices is being displayed on 'Bluetooth Devices'. The device is correctly paired and data is being transmitted. Is there something missing?

Comment: Have you tried this way? `'One way to find the name of the port created is to call the System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames method before and after the SetServiceState call and see which name is new.'`

Comment: Those registry keys are used and filled by the Windows PnP device manager.  If the device is installed and displayed by the device manager, it must have a key tree there.  If you are using a Bluetooth USB dongle that is solely dedicated to your device, then you are dealing with a USB device and it will have a somewhat similar entry based on its PnP ID under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB`